# .Net Maui - Is it possible to access the native Notes App when Offline?

Tags: .net, xaml, maui

My mobile app requirements include the ability to log data offline.  Since data entry, at this point, is minimal I'm wondering if rather than developing offline capabilities, which doesn't look trivial, I could leverage "Notes".  The app would notify that "Internet service is not available" via (popup) and give an option to temporarily record the data in "Notes" until back within service.  Ideally the "OK, create a Note" button would open "Notes" and initiate a note... something like:

(Note)

- Production Log - 2022-06-24 (pre-filled)
- WBS Name: Clearing and Grading (label prefilled, value entered by User)
- Start Station: (label prefilled, value entered by User)
- End Station: (label prefilled, value entered by User)
- Quantity: (label prefilled, value entered by User)

Once the User is back within service, they could reference the note (optional) to create a Production Log... no automation required.

1. Is this possible?
2. If so, do you believe Users would view this as clever or cumbersome?
3. What is the general level of effort, on a scale of 1 to 5, to develop offline capabilities?

Thanks!

Comment: why not just log notes to an sqlite db and then sync when online?

Comment: So are you suggesting developing a "Notes" Page that works offline and uses a local sqllite db for storage or developing the entire app to work offline?  Any suggested resources on this?  Really appreciate the input!

Comment: I don't know anything about your app or your requirements, so... whichever suits your needs better.

Comment: Don't send them to Notes app. Its straightforward to make a simple notes page in your app, and store locally. If you haven't used sqlite, for first version, don't use a db: create a folder with a file per note written while offline. Effort level 2. Later, you might decide to cache ALL notes locally - not just those written while offline - for a better offline experience - at that time, learn sqlite. Effort level 3.

Comment: Really appreciate the suggestions... will give a try next week!